# Code inside simple switch case or if statement does not execute

Tags: c#, console

In the following, my code inside switch case "c" does not execute. Nothing happens! If the input is "q" the isOwner = false execute just fine. This makes no sense to me. Please help!

```
// Customer information
string customerName = "";
string customerPassword = "";
int customerCredits = 0;

string input = "";

Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to my console Pet Store");
Console.WriteLine ("Type in your name?");
customerName = Console.ReadLine ();
Console.WriteLine ("Type in your password?");
customerPassword = Console.ReadLine ();

if (customerName == "owner" && customerPassword == "1234") {

    bool isOwner = true;    // Launch the owner interface when isOwner is true

    while (isOwner) {
        Console.Clear ();
        Console.WriteLine ("You are logged in as Owner");
        Console.WriteLine ("[q] Quit");
        Console.WriteLine ("[c] Create new product");
        Console.WriteLine ("[d] Create new animal");
        Console.WriteLine ("[i] View all items in the store");
        Console.WriteLine ("[t] View all customers");

        // string input;
        input = Console.ReadLine ();

        switch (input) {
            case "q":
                isOwner = false;
                break;
            case "c":
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("What type of product do you want to create?");
                break;
        }
    }
} // END of owner interface
```

Btw: Ive also tried the same with an if statement, but with same result.

Comment: The input = Console.ReadLine (); - Are you typing input and pressing enter when it gets to that point?

Comment: Follow the code carefully. When you get to `case "c"`, you clear the console and ask what product to create. You then *immediately* return to the start of the while loop (`while(isOwner)`), clear the console again, and then print out the menu. Your code *is* executing, but you're clearing the console so quickly you won't see it. I would suggest removing `Console.Clear()` while you're debugging

Comment: this actually helped me find out what the problem was, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is running, it's just not waiting after it displays the prompt. Try adding something like `Console.ReadKey();` after you print the prompt: `Console.WriteLine("What type of product do you want to create?")`.

```
switch (input) {
        case "q":
            isOwner = false;
            break;
        case "c":
            Console.Clear ();
            Console.WriteLine("What type of product do you want to create?");
            Console.ReadKey();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: yes exactly that was also what I found out after trying other techniques with the loop. It excetuted my code but because it did not wait for any input it excecuted to the end very fast. Console.ReadLine(); worked

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange. But i have assumption:
is it possible that char 'c' is not english? A lot of languages has similar letters, but this letters have different codes.

Try to delete 'c' and type it again with eng keyboard layout.